# Checking if an XML is valid in doc($XML)

Tags: xslt

What is the best way to determine whether the XML passed in the doc() function is a valid XML? I need to run different code whether if it is valid or not. I have tried using xsl:choose, but the doc() function would make my code crash if the XML passed in was invalid.

I have tried the xsl:try and xsl:catch but I don't know how to dynamically set a variable (to use later) on whether the XML is valid or not.

Comment: There is the function `doc-available` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-doc-available which might help, depending on what exactly you want to check, I am not sure what you consider "valid" XML as that usually refers to validating a well-formed XML against a DTD or schema or other grammar.

Comment: Oh yes, that is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I have morphed that comment into an answer you can hopefully accept if the function solves your problem, that way your question will be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an XPath function `doc-available` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-doc-available you can use to check whether a resource at a URL you pass in is parseable into a document node so you can use that in a check with e.g.: `if (doc-available('foo.xml')) then doc('foo.xml')//items else ()`.